# Error while installing ionic in cmd

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, npm

I keep getting below error while trying to install ionic using cmd

I have installed Node JS before this

```
$ npm install -g cordova ionic
npm ERR! code SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN
npm ERR! errno SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova failed, reason: self
signed certificate in certificate chain

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\samar_000\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-07-
23T10_58_18_779Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 npm set strict-ssl false
```

Or you can upgrade your npm as suggested [here](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/78165272245/more-help-with-selfsignedcertinchain-and-npm)

Comment: This is an _insecure_ workaround, it should not be the solution. We should try and figure out why OP was presented the wrong certificate to begin with. By disabling this, you may just open yourself up to a MITM attack.